# Alternate value in join with update

Tags: mysql

I have an `item` table that has the fields `item_id`, `priority` and a bunch of other fields. I also have an `item_priority` table that has two fields: `item_id` and `priority`. Not every item in the `item` table has a matching record in `item_priority`.

I want to update the `item` table to set the priorities based on the `item_priority` table. For all of the items where there is no match, I want the `priority` to be -1.

I can run the following:

```
update item set priority = -1
```

and

```
update item 
join item_priority on item.item_id = item_priority.item_id
set item.priority = item_priority.priority
```

This will get me what I need. But is there a way to do this in a single query?

*Note: I understand that this design is not optimal, but it has to be done this way for a different reason. All I want is to accomplish this in a single query without redesigning the tables.*

Answer (score 2):

```
update item 
left join item_priority on item.item_id = item_priority.item_id
set item.priority = IF (item_priority.priority is null, -1, item_priority.priority)
```

Here's another option. Is that any faster for you?

```
update item
join (select item.item_id, ifnull(item_priority.priority, -1) as priority
      from item 
      left join item_priority on item.item_id = item_priority.item_id) new_priority on item.item_id = new_priority.item_id
set item.priority = new_priority.priority
```

Comment: One quick edit. 'join' needs to change to 'left join'

Comment: Sorry for withdrawing my accepted answer - the query is awfully slow even for a few thousand items. I don't want to give others the false impression that this worked. I am giving you a +1 for trying to help. Thanks.

Comment: Just ran a test. My item has 1261568 entries all set to priority 5000 initially. My item_priority table has 4948 non consecutive item_id's and priorities with random values.

My first query took 15 seconds. The second was actually slower at 26 seconds. 3.3GHz 2-core cpu.

I will be interested to see if someone comes up with something faster than the first query above. How does your cpu compare?

Comment: My results were about the same (relatively speaking). Again, your answer works, but it's just slow. I am curious to see if there is a faster way. In the meantime, I'm using the two consecutive updates, which are both super fast. Thanks for all your help so far.